# deploying UUPSUpgradeable Proxy contract in hardhat script vs Remix

Tags: remix, etherscan, hardhat-deploy, proxy-contracts

I have some doubts regarding proxy contracts, I am using UUPSUpgradeable proxy to upgrade my contract, for deployment I have used tools  Remix and hardhat with deploy script.
When I am using Remix to deploy my contract it works fine , it's deploying what I am expected to do so ..
Proxy address : https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x60533DF6CeB28016546B1d8456eD0db319fEa23D#code

When I am using harhat to deploy my contract it works little much different , its deploying some additional contract which I have not imported in my main contract
Proxy address : https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x197D7815d87C21d508A755fea6ba15743967C2Ab#code

deploy script in hardhat:

```
async function main() {

const erc1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("test");
const ERC1155 = await upgrades.deployProxy(erc1155);
await ERC1155.deployed();
console.log("test address:", ERC1155.address);
}
```

My question are simple why I am getting additional imported contract like beconProxy.sol , UpgradeableBeacon.sol while deploying in hardhat and how to avoid them ..

Comment: Have you found the answer? I experience the same.